# Does having single name space in 3 linked c++ projects opposite to MVC concept?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, c++-cli

I'm working on c++/CLI project using windows forms for GUI, basically we shall work using MVC concept so we built up the project using 3 linked projects (1 for model, one for viewer and one for control), 
so after extracting code documentation, I find single namespace for the whole project so does this make conflict with MVC concept ?

thanks alot

Comment: No not at all. Many libraries wrap their entire library in a single namespace, e.g. `std::`, `boost::`, etc.

Comment: C++ using Windows Forms is *not* C++, but C++/CLI (and you should tag appropriately).